# Using CreateProcessAsUser in python does not pass the user's environment to the created process

Tags: python, windows-services, user-environment

First thank you for your time reading this question.

I start an app executable (lets call it *MyApp.exe*) successfully from my windows service under the ***Interactive user*** using the following code:

```
#MyWindowsService.py

console_session_id = win32ts.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
console_user_token = win32ts.WTSQueryUserToken(console_session_id)

my_app_path= os.path.normpath(r"/Path\to\MyApp.exe")
startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
priority = win32con.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
handle, thread_id ,pid, tid = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(console_user_token, my_app_path, None, None, None, True, priority, None, None, startup)
```

From inside MyApp I need to get the environment paths that belong to the *interactive user*. For example I use the following code to get the path for user's %appdata%:

```
#MyApp.py

user_app_data_path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
```

It should return:

C:\Users\ ***Interactive-user-name*** \AppData\Roaming

However the returned value is:

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming

Which means although MyApp.exe is started under *interactive user's* name, it gets the environment for *SYSTEM* user that the windows service is running under.

My question is how I can get the environment paths that belong to the user not system.

Many thank,

**P.S. I am using py2exe to convert MyApp and Windows service into executables.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, in case any one is interested:

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) if the environment is not explicitly specified, the process inherits the environment of the parent. Using [this](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32profile__CreateEnvironmentBlock_meth.html) one can get the environment and pass it on to CreateProcessAsUser.

Simply follow the environment word in the following code.

```
#MyWindowsService.py

console_session_id = win32ts.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
console_user_token = win32ts.WTSQueryUserToken(console_session_id)

my_app_path= os.path.normpath(r"/Path\to\MyApp.exe")
startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
priority = win32con.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
environment = win32profile.CreateEnvironmentBlock(console_user_token, False)
handle, thread_id ,pid, tid = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(console_user_token, my_app_path, None, None, None, True, priority, environment, None, startup)
```

Comment: jan, Thanks a gazillion times. This solved my issue!